# why flat rate always show ₹5.00 whether changed in admin panel

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

I need your help.why the changes in flat rate not affecting.If I disabled it shows and whether i changed it shows "fixed  ₹5.00".Please help me i am confused on what to do.

Please check this :

```
http://qwertykart.com/
login:jis123@gmail.com password:jis123
http://qwertykart.com/checkout/cart/
```

Comment: is the multi store or single store site ?

Comment: are you telling, if you disabled flat rate shipping method than also it showing 5 $ as shipping charge ?

Comment: yeah and also changes not affecting...

Comment: what shipping method are you using now?

Comment: free shipping and flat rate....

Comment: but no changes is affecting in flat rate...

Comment: means now you disabled flat rate and using only `free shipping` but still it showing as `5 $` , is it ? did you cleared cache & tried in private window ?

Comment: ya cleared cache and var folder...

Comment: if product rate is above 500 only free shipping less than 500 flat rate($50.00)

Comment: above 500 working fine

Comment: sorry didt understood.

Comment: if the product rate is above 500 there is no problem its free shipping

Comment: if  rate less than 500 i am using flat rate

Comment: if rate is less than 500 if you are using flat rate means than why you disabled it ?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Install_Controller_Router_Install' not found in /home/rivulets/public_html/qwertykart.com/includes/src/Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front.php on line 138

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check for Current Configuration Scope if you are using a default settings then select as Main Website and then  disable clear cache and check.
 It should work.

[image]

Comment: thanks again...and again....Great problem solving skill ..Big Salute..

Comment: Good job Ashish

Comment: Thank u all of you.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `System > Configuration > Shipping Method`. Now change `Current Configuration Scope` to `Main Website`.

Then check `Flat Rate` -> `Price`. I think it must be set to 5. You should use `Use Default` checkbox OR change it to your requirement